# Mock static using powermockito when the static method is called in from some other method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermockito

Code sample :

```
public class A{

    public static B connectA(){
        String new = "java";
        B b = new B("new");

        return b;
    }

    public void A(){
       B b = connectA();
    }
}



public class B{

  public B(String A){
     methodB(new);
  }

 public static String methodB(String new){
      return new;
 }


}
```

So, now if i am testing method "A", :

1. when it calls "connectA() method", i want it to return a mocked object that i   want

OR

2. when "new B" is called i want it to return a mocked object i want

it works if the connectA() method is not static, but i dont know how to make it work if its static using powermockito and mockito

so test class would be somethinng like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class,B.class})
public class ATest(){
    public void testMethodA(){
       PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(BMock);
       A a = new A();
       a.A();
    }
 }
```

where BMock is any object i create!

Any possible solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this would be,

when i do mock like this :

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(B.class);
PowerMockito.when(B.methodB).thenReturn("My mocked String");
```

then here ("My mocked string") is a different instance of object that is used or we can say has different object id (like : a5Gbd@ass)

but when actually the method is called in the constructor of method B, it is called with this variable passed in as "new", which again has a different object id (like : affac@das), so what happens is powermockito thinks that the method which is called now in the constructor and the method which we are referring to when we are mocking it - both are different.

and that is why its said as one of the limitation of powermockito.

but i had a work around for this, it would work if somehow you are able to pass the same instance of object at both the places, this way powermockito knows we are reffering to same method.

again, it depends on how your code is structured , but in my code i saw it was possible and so it helped.

one more thing that helped me was accessing a private variable using powermockito, so if anyone needs it:

Whitebox.getInternalState(classObjectNameCreated, "variableName");

ask questions, if nothing is understood, i know i am not good at it!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try add

```
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(B.class);
```

But I would refactor code and use com.google.inject.Provider for creating instance of B class. It is easy to mock it and you wouldn't need PowerMockito.

**Update.**

This code works correct for me(I add getter within class A)

```
package main;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

@RunWith(org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class,B.class})
public class ATests{ 

    @Test
    public void testMethodA() throws Exception{
        B BMock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(BMock);
        A a = new A();
        Assert.assertEquals(BMock, a.getB());
    }
 }
```

**According injectors.**
See reference https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders
It is dificult to understand what do you want and what is the logic in your class. So only you know your business rule and where to inject. Instead Providers you can use factories. But there is a "holy war" about using factories.

Comment: i tried using mockStatic, it dosent work!

i haven't used com.google.inject, could you please give an example for that ?

Comment: The mock static only works, if i am calling the static method directly from test class, but now when its called by something else !

Comment: Something is strange because your code works correctly on my configuration without mockstatic. It means that I give correct mock for a.getB().